# Install make4ht with MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, tex4ht, htlatex, lua, make4ht

I am trying to install make4ht on a system running MiKTex.  The recommended instructions https://d800fotos.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/create-e-books-from-latex-tex-files-ebook-aus-latex-tex-dateien-erstellen/ are specific to TexLive and so I am looking for some help getting this setup.  I believe the root of the problem is either that MiKTeX doesn't have texmf directory or I can't figure out how to run the files themselves.

Instruction summary:
I downloaded the  zip files and unpacked them in the recommended directory structure:

`.../texmf/scripts/lua/make4ht/[root zip extracted]`

`.../texmf/tex/latex/tex4ebook/[root zip extracted]`

I added `.../texmf/` to the roots of MikTex settings and when I click apply I see a MiKTeX maintenance dialog box scan the files.

Next to make `make4ht` runnable (as per the answer below) - `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\make4ht.bat` only contains

`texlua "F:\...\texmf\scripts\lua\make4ht\make4ht" %*`

Sample Tex File:  eqntests.tex

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
        \begin{equation}
            \text{C~=~}{\frac{a}{b}}
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

To compile my tex file using `make4ht` I run

`FOR /R %%A IN (*.tex) DO ("make4ht.bat" "%%~nxA")`

But I get an error message as described: `[string "Make:htlatex{}..."]:1: attempt to index global 'Make' (a nil value) .../texmf/scripts/lua/make4ht/mkutils.lua:281: assertion failed!`

I appear to be missing the `Make` program.  What required program provides the `Make` command?

Comment: @EngBIRD this `Make` is part of `make4ht` and it is defined in `make4ht-lib.lua` file. is this file missing?

Comment: @michal.h21 It is indeed present.  `...\texmf\scripts\lua\make4ht\make4ht-lib.lua` do I need to create a build bat file for all `*.lua` files?

Comment: @EngBIRD no, is is needed only for `make4ht`. does `kpsewhich make4ht-lib.lua` find anything? (if you run it from different directory than make4ht is installed)

Comment: @michal.h21 Yes, the kpsewhich call successfully reports the full file path.  And I can confirm that I have run kpsewhich from different drives and it always reports the same file path.

Comment: @EngBIRD I changed module declaration `make4ht-lib`, maybe it could help (it used method which is deprecated in Lua 5.2). you can try to upgrade make4ht

Comment: @michal.h21 Excellent.  This works and I can compile my document.  No svg file produced though and the png file looks even lower resolution than the first instance, but definitely one step closer!

Comment: @EngBIRD fine :) if you don't get `svg`, update your previous question with your `mk4` and config files, as well with possible error messages from compilation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added installation instructions to [make4ht readme](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht#installation), I will copy Windows instructions here:

See a [guide by Volker Gottwald](https://d800fotos.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/create-e-books-from-latex-tex-files-ebook-aus-latex-tex-dateien-erstellen/) on how  to install `make4ht` and tex4ebook`.

Create a batch file for `make4ht` somewhere in the `path`:

```
texlua "C:\full\path\to\make4ht" %*
```

you can find directories in the path with

```
path
```

command, or you can create new directory and [add it to the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Note for `Miktex` users: you may need to create `texmf` directory first. See    [this answer on TeX.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Comment: Thanks for the answer:  I can't quite tell if my implementation of your solution was unsuccessful or if I have missed an important underlying requirement.    I get an error message as described:  `[string "Make:htlatex{}..."]:1: attempt to index global 'Make' (a nil value)
.../texmf/scripts/lua/make4ht/mkutils.lua:281: assertion failed!`

Comment: @EngBIRD: Make your problem description so that other can *reproduce* the problem. Add the exact call you are using, show the minimal document etc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated my question to make it reproducible (on both of my computers), but I honestly think that the solution posted above should have worked - and would have if my computer had the required prerequisites.  I.e. whatever program gives ` Make` as I think the error I posted just indicates that  `Make` is missing.

Comment: I don't get this error, but I get always `latex: Not enough room in an internal buffer.`. @michal.h21: Is there any way to see the actual latex call a "make4ht file" call is doing?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added latex call print. and also slightly modified some parameters which looked suspicious anw which were different than `htlatex` uses

Comment: without having made extensive tests: the latex call line looks *very* long and I guess miktex doesn't like this. Wouldn't it be better to put all this code in in a file and to use then `latex \input{4htparams}\input{filename}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is copied from `htlatex` command. Does `htlatex` produce this error as well?

Comment: htlatex works ok, but the call is not completly identical: e.g. jobname is missing and the quoting is different. I will have to do some tests to find what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer maybe the quoting is the problem. but is strange as `make4ht` with TL in Windows doesn't have any problems

Comment: Well the (single) quotes are certainly the problem - imho they are rather dubiuos as they don't have an official status in windows batch files. And on the command line you would `! I can't find '.`with texlive too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've found that there are no quotes around LaTeX commands in `htlatex.bat`, so I removed them on Windows.